# Advanced SSRS report functionality in a Microsoft.WinForms.ReportViewer

Tags: vb.net, reportviewer, ssrs-2008-r2

Viewing SSRS reports in a Microsoft.WinForms.ReportViewer. Is there a way to get advanced SSRS funtionality (e.g. flyouts / hyperlinks) to work in the report viewer? [The above functions DO work in a Forms.WebBrowser control.]

The two functionalities that I want to implement are as follows:

- Report has ACTIONS that cause alternate reports to be run.

[SSRS report properties of text box in the tablix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RQre3.png)

[Report behaviour when using older viewer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9FMIy.png)

- Report has flyout functionality.

[Group properties from the tablix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fn1E9.png)

[Report behaviour when using older viewer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2rs5n.png)

The intent of the new viewer is to get some menu functionality into our report viewer that our users are requesting.

[Report viewer with e-mail functionality added to forward report(s) to clients](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B3luG.png)

The fundamental problems would appear to be because the ReportViewer control (that is being used in the new previewer) is only allowing a fully rendered document. Is there a way to make it retain the SSRS functionality?

Comment: To get better help, you you should provide some background, an example and more details to what you are trying to do. As it is, your question lacks enough information for somebody to be able to help you in any meaningful way.

Comment: Updated with images and more content.